# add calculated fields based on year by year performance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, calculated-field

I am generating a report about sales and want to know if there is a way to calculate an aggregated column based on dates. e.g. Data stored in a matrix is orders, column is month and calender year. each month shows 3 years. I want the calculated field to take the most recent months and calculate the percentage change between them. see the following image to understand what I mean.

[image]

As you can see there are 3 years. I want to ignore 2008 and wnat my calculated field to do the percentage value of increase from 2009 to 2010. The design of this is shown in following image.
[image]

Regarding the other question, see the following images:

In the design view my matrix looks like this:
[image]

The output is report is:

[image]

The original data is:

[image]

And I just want to see the recent 2 years and ignore the rest of the years, like follows:

[image]

Thank you all in advance

Comment: try and show the expected output screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your dataset returns one row per month/year you cannot use a calculated field.

However, you can calculate the increment or decrement percentage using an expression.

Add a column to the right under the `Month` column group.

[image]

Add the following expression to the cell is highlighted in my matrix.

```
=(Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value=2010,Fields!Total_Ord.Value,0))-
Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value=2009,Fields!Total_Ord.Value,0))
)/Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value=2009,Fields!Total_Ord.Value,0))
```

> Note my formula is `(2010-2009)/2009` it will return a positive
>   percentage if 2010 `Total_Ord` is greater than the 2009 `Total_Ord`.
>   Otherwise the percentage will be negative.

This is the preview of the matrix:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Calculate percentage inc/dec of the last year and the last previous year.

Use this expression to compare the last year in my case 2015 and the last previous year 2014:

```
=(Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value=Max(Fields!Year.Value),Fields!Sales.Value,0))-
Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value=Max(Fields!Year.Value)-1,Fields!Sales.Value,0))
)/Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value=Max(Fields!Year.Value)-1,Fields!Sales.Value,0))
```

It will preview this matrix:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: it certainly helped. is there a more generic way of doing it? like in sql we can use getdate() and work from there

Comment: @Faiz, what do you mean by generic way? Do you want to use dynamic years? If so share your dataset and explain how you take years from database.

Comment: By generic i mean that, the most recent year in a given month might not always be 2010, it could be 2012, and i dont want to manually tell it to do it on 2012, i want it to figure out the most recent is 2012 and its comparing to 2011. or when its 2011 most recent then compare to previous year 2010. The data set is pretty much similar to adventureworksDW2012, and i get the year from calenderYear column.

Comment: hey. I was trying something new, to only see the recent two years and i made 2 columns. The first column had this expression '=MAX(Fields!Year.Value)-1' and the second column has the expression '=MAX(Fields!Year.Value)'. I expected to only see 2 year columns but it shows all of them and on the last column it sums up all the orders. I will add photos on the main question not sure how to add them here in comment

Comment: @Faiz, post a new question for the new requeriments you are trying since the first question posted here was solved. Also the new question will have the visibility it deserves.

Comment: sorry about that. here is the link if you could help please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896120/using-condition-to-set-ssrs-matrix-column-name