# Using condition to set SSRS matrix column name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was trying something new, using matrix and only want to  see the recent two years and i made 2 columns. The first column had this expression '=MAX(Fields!Year.Value)-1' and the second column has the expression '=MAX(Fields!Year.Value)'. I expected to only see 2 year columns but it shows all of them and on the last column it sums up all the orders. See the photos below:

In the design view my matrix looks like this:

[image]

The output in report is:

[image]

The problem is that year 2007 only exists in another year and month, but i dont know why it shows up here. see the image next to see the original data.

The original data is:

[image]

And I just want to see the recent 2 years and ignore the rest of the years, like follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding each year order, instead you have to add only those that correspond to your column year. For previous last year you have to sum only its orders values.

Use these expressions to `Sum` only the two recent years orders:

Previous last year:

```
=Sum(
iif(Fields!Year.Value=Max(Fields!Year.Value)-1,Fields!Total_Ord.Value,0)
)
```

Last year:

```
=Sum(
IIF(Fields!Year.Value=MAX(Fields!Year.Value),Fields!Total_Ord.Value,0)
)
```

**UPDATE**: Don't group by year and just add two columns under the `Month` column group.

This is the matrix you should have:

[image]

It will preview:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: From what i understand. I should keep the expressions i had on the year column group and add the expression to the corresponding row data. After i did that and previewed the report, it shows the data as: `2007 2008 2009 2010` with values `0 0 0 29`. the 29 count is correct for 2010, but as you showed i didnt expect the 2007 and 2008 to show and 2009 to show 7 as in the original data

Comment: @Faiz, Delete the Year column group, check my update.